# zend 2 widgetized contents

Tags: widget, action, zend-framework2, dispatch

i am trying to create a widgetized contents..
basically i want to have blocks in my layout that gets populated from different module/controller/actions ...

i tried using `$this->action` in view but it seems that action has been removed in ZF2 (or not ?)
service manager cant find it :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for action
```

i also tried `forward action helper` inside a module's `'Zend\Mvc\Application::dispatch'` event but can't call forward becuase there is no controller ????

so how can i load blocks(different module/controller/actions) in my layout ???

Comment: Please see http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/
This is all i can suggest on that topic without specific code problems

Comment: you should also check that the url pass in the action in also map in `module.config.php` file. This error also occur due to that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what i did:

- Created a view helper for each block
- created a index in module config file to hold a list of blockable view helpers
- created a table to hold the list of blocks and their configurations
- created a "new block action" witch load the list of blockable helpers

  - user picks a helper type and gets redirected to the other page
  - here helper specific configs are loaded

    - the form in this page firs a event to collect helper config
    - modules can handle this event and create the config fieldset and give it to the form
  - i also load a list of block positions from my templates ini config file
- created a "blocks" view helper witch accepts one parameter "block position" and then searches the blocks table for a match for that position

  - if any found : each items associated view helper is executed and the outputs are collected and returned to the view